# why it dosen't show all the days of some months?

Tags: php, laravel

i made a calendar using laravel but it dosen't works with all months , it showes some months and others not

This is how it looks when the app works just fine (just for some months)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/coPrc.png

this is what happen if i pick the next or previous month

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG2fx.png

```
// Get prev & next month
if ($dat) {
    $ym = $dat;
} else {
    // This month
    $ym = date('Y-m');
}
// Check format
$timestamp = strtotime($ym . '-01');  // the first day of the month
if ($timestamp === false) {
    $ym = date('Y-m');
    $timestamp = strtotime($ym . '-01');
}
// Today (Format:2019-07-30)
$today = date('Y-m-j');
$current= date('Y-m');
// Title (Format:July, 2019)
$title = date('F, Y', $timestamp);
// Create prev & next month link
$prev = date('Y-m', strtotime('-1 month', $timestamp));
$next = date('Y-m', strtotime('+1 month', $timestamp));
// Number of days in the month
$day_count = date('t', $timestamp);
$exploded = explode('-',$dat);
$count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$exploded[1],$exploded[0]);
// 1:Mon 2:Tue 3: Wed ... 7:Sun
$str = date('N', $timestamp);
// Array for calendar
$weeks = [];
$week = '';
$day_count=(int)$count;
// Add empty cell(s)
$week .= str_repeat('<div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell "><div><div><span>', $str - 1);
for ($day = 1; $day <= $day_count; $day++, $str++) {
    $date = $ym . '-' . $day;
    if ($today == $date) {
        $week .= '<div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell " style="background-color: #dddada;"><div><div><span>';
    } else {
        $week .= '<div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>';
    }
    $week .= $day . '</span></div></div></div>';

    // Sunday OR last day of the month
    if ($str % 7 == 0 || $day == $day_count) {
        // last day of the month
        if ($day == $day_count && $str % 7 != 0) {
            // Add empty cell(s)
            $week .= str_repeat('<span>', 7 - $str % 7);
        }
        $weeks[] = '<div class="row calendar-week">' . $week . '</div>';
        $week = '';
    }
}
return view('TL_Views.index')->with(['weeks'=>$weeks,'title'=>$title,'prev'=>$prev,'next'=>$next,'current'=>$current,'count'=>$count]);
```

this is the code in the view

```
@foreach ($weeks as $day)
    {!! $day !!}
@endforeach
```

Comment: `$week .= str_repeat('<div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>', $str - 1);` is messing up the number of divs, if you look at the browser source. You need to close those divs and spans

Comment: it's not this because it works with some months and others not

Comment: Look at the mass of numbers to the left of Monday, and then look at the browser source with proper indentation. There are a ton of divs and spans that are not closed. I was able to fix it locally with `$week .= str_repeat('<div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span></span></div></div></div>', $str - 1);`

Comment: Thank you Very much it's working properly